# Trying to use PubNub library with ESPDUINO (arduino with ESP8266 WiFi)

Tags: c++, arduino, pubnub, esp8266

I'm attempting to use the PubNub library on a [Cactus Micro Rev2](http://wiki.aprbrother.com/wiki/Cactus_Micro_Rev2) dev board. This board is basically an Arduino Lillypad USB with an attached ESP8266 WiFi chip.

**Goal: Use PubNub to subscribe to a channel using the ESP8266 WiFi interface.**

The PubNub library indicates that it is designed to work with an Ethernet or WiFi shield.

The Cactus Micro uses the espduino library where it communicates with WiFi using a SLIP stream. (I think).

How do I leverage the espduino library instead of the Ethernet or WiFi shield library?

For context:
[PubNub Library](https://github.com/pubnub/arduino)

```
/* By default, the PubNub library is built to work with the Ethernet
* shield. WiFi shield support can be enabled by commenting the
* following line and commenting out the line after that. Refer
* to the PubNubJsonWifi sketch for a complete example. */
//#define PubNub_Ethernet
#define PubNub_WiFi


#if defined(PubNub_Ethernet)
#include <Ethernet.h>
#define PubNub_BASE_CLIENT EthernetClient

#elif defined(PubNub_WiFi)
#include <WiFi.h>
#define PubNub_BASE_CLIENT WiFiClient
```

[ESPDUINO Library](https://github.com/AprilBrother/espduino)

To use the espduino library in the Arduino code with MQTT, I do something like the following, because the espduino.h has an MQTT class.

```
// ESP8266 WiFi 
#include <espduino.h>
#define PIN_ENABLE_ESP 13
#define SSID  ".interwebs"
#define PASS  "meraki81"
boolean wifiConnected = false;
ESP esp(&Serial1, &Serial, PIN_ENABLE_ESP);

// MQTT
#include <mqtt.h>
MQTT mqtt(&esp);

... snip 
mqtt.connect("myBroker", 1883, false);
```

I would then expect/hope to do something like this to use PubNub

```
PUBNUB pubnub(&esp);

... snip

pubnub.publish("news", "OLED board online");
```

But that doesn't work obviously.

The expected technique is to use the WiFiClient class from the wifi shield library:

```
// PubNub 
WiFiClient *client;

client = PubNub.publish("news", "OLED board online");
```

Any suggestions, workarounds, libraries that could help? I'm more comfortable with NodeJS then C/C++ so just trying to wrap my head around it.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Cory this sounds like a lot of fun.  That board is tiny!

Comment: try moving past the pubnub client and use a REST call to test network connectivity.  **PUBLISH:**  http://pubsub.pubnub.com/publish/demo/demo/0/hello_world/0/%22Hello%20World%22 - now also be connected to the **Developer Console:** https://www.pubnub.com/console/?channel=hello_world&sub=demo&pub=demo in your chrome web browser.

Comment: Great idea to just use REST. For my purpose, this will work fine. Thanks!

Comment: great! :-D that is awesome.